# Spring boot Mvc multi servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to build a spring boot application with multiple servlet, to add specific rest controller on each.

Unfortunaly, i've a 404 when i do a request. I suspect a bug in spring-web source, on UrlPathHelper#getLookupPathForRequest : line 173

```
if (!"".equals(rest)) {
  return rest;
}
```

why not

```
if (notEmpty(rest)) {
  return rest;
}
```

with rest = "" all it's ok, so it's a bug, or a misconfiguration on my app ?

https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/mvc-multi-context

thanks

Comment: How are you making the request. Could you provide me the http path you are calling ?

Comment: Why woul dyou need multiple dispatcher servlets for that? A single one is perfectly capable of handling that.

Comment: This is a simple POST 
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/two' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{}'

Comment: @M.Deinum servlet path for same business. my sample is /api/one, /api/two, but there is /private, ect ... i don't want to have @RequestMapping("/api/...). i wan't possibility to have same controller on different path

Comment: Then again why would you need multiple servlets? A single servlet can be assigned to multiple paths. Or maybe even better, a single one that maps to `/` (the default) and use an `UrlRewritingFilter` to do what you want.

Comment: The goal is :

- a root spring context with shared bean
- a path (like /api, /private, /my-path, ect ...) whith only his business on spring context
- possibility to have a business package shared to multiple path (/api to consumer (different securities filter), /bo to a backoffice)
with that, i can have /api/my-controller-mapping/my-endpoint , /bo/path/.../my-controller-mapping/my-endpoint

I've done this configuration on spring framework, and i try to do same, on spring boot